# ASP.net 5 Site Deployed to Azure with Defaults hangs

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a site with the following project.json:

```html
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Http": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Owin": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },
  "commands": {
    "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:45576",
    "run": "run server.urls=http://localhost:45577",
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:45578"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
```

It seems to deploy to the instance of azure Web App (set to 64 bit always on with php disabled and .net 4.6)

But then when you try and access the site, it just sits and hangs and never responds.

Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: Update: Eventually I get a 500 error with no details.

Comment: Does it work as expected on your local machine?

Comment: When you say default, do you mean you're creating a new ASP.NET web application with which ASP.NET 5 templates? Empty, Web Api, Web Application

Comment: Are you deploying via VS or via git? This test project works with both: https://github.com/davidebbo-test/AspNet5RC1. With git, you need Basic or higher plan due to higher disk space usage (will be solved later).

Comment: @DavidEbbo In the GitHub repo, are the global.json and the .sln required to use GitDeploy to Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the problem is not having a default `web.config` file that contains a large value for `startupTimeLimit`

Create a default `web.config` file in your `wwwroot` that contains the following

```
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" startupTimeLimit="3600"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

what happens is that without that large value the default is 10 seconds and the process doesn't have enough time to start, so it's killed and launched again and never actually finishes.